# How can I save a string of numbers with quotation marks around it, so I can pull from it later? (currently getting err. 509)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where the person using it may or may not put an "x" in a certain cell.

Depending on if the "x" is there, two sets of variables need to be stored to use later.

So, here is the formula I am trying to get working:

**In cell I6**:

```
=IF(J3="x",""18","19","20","21","22","23","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"",
""6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"")
```

I was storing them like [18,19,20,...].  However, later I need to be able to run another formula to randomize it, which we'll get to in minute.

**In cell I9**, there is to be a text version of this:

```
=CELL("contents",$I$6)
```

Finally, **in cell I12**:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,15), CELL("contents", $I$9))
```

...So, my question is, either:

1. How can I get the quoted formulas in cell I6 to save with the quotes?

...or,

2. How can I get cell I12 to parse the string from cell I9, to add the quotes?

...or,

3. How else can I make this work?

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: The edit queue is full so I can't make a small change, but I would suggest breaking up the formula by putting a new line after the "8"" to make it more readable for future viewers. Also preface and end the formula with ```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to first store the values and then randomly select them? You may want to use SEQUENCE in combination with MOD to get your values and run a random choose over that?

Comment: @P.b - Can you show an example of that?  I am actually a rather green Excel user.

Comment: To answer _How can I get the quoted formulas in cell I6 to save with the quotes?_ : you escape the quotes, like this `=IF(J3="x","""18"",""19"",""20"",""21"",""22"",""23"",""0"",""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8""","""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10"",""11"",""12"",""13"",""14"",""15"",""16"",""17"",""18"",""19"",""20""")
`

Comment: That said, that won't give you what you want.  the result is a single string, which `Choose` won't understand.

Comment: To answer _How else can I make this work?_ : first tell us what your desired outcome is.  Also, which version of Excel (if it's 365 then there are many more options)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I just realized that it didn't get the desired result.  

So, I have a sheet that gets loaded up to a software.  The sheet has a column of hours.  Those hours need to be randomly selected.  However, the hours also need to be between a certain time US-Eastern.  

I have employees in another country.  The software that the sheet gets loaded up to will load the time relative to where the user is who is loading it up.  

So, if the user in the other country puts 13 in the hour field (1pm), then it would get posted in the US at 1am.

I need to be able to account for this.

Comment: @BPmkt please edit your Q to include 1) tags for the software you're actually using 2) some representative sample data 3) your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I didn't have the newer version of Excel, I ended up changing how I handled the needed ranges.

This is what I used:

```
=IF($'Date Calc'.J3="x", IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,2)=1,RANDBETWEEN(0,9),RANDBETWEEN(18,23)), RANDBETWEEN(6,21))
```

Thanks everyone!  I really appreciate the help and feedback!

Comment: doh! Much simpler than trying to combine the arrays, nice idea

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I would try to prevent all the double quotes, though there is probably a perfectly good way to do it with them.

Instead I would keep it as a single string, then use `FILTERXML` if you have the newest version of Excel. So the `IF` statement would be:

```
=IF(J3="x","18,19,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8",
"6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20")
```

And the random result would be determined with something like

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(F3,",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
RANDBETWEEN(1,15))
```

For example:

[image]

and

[image]

If the cell with the `IF` is just used as a helper cell, than you can even do it in one go with something like the below (spaces, "-0"s, and "+1"s used to for readability and clarity):

```
=IF(J3="x",

INDEX(IF(SEQUENCE(15)<=9,
INDEX(SEQUENCE(8-0+1,1,0,1), SEQUENCE(15)),
INDEX(SEQUENCE(23-18+1,1,18,1), SEQUENCE(15)-(8-0+1))),
RANDBETWEEN(1,15)),

RANDBETWEEN(6,20))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have the most recent version.  Actually I am working between Google Docs and Libreoffice.  Most things are cross-compatible, but these don't seem to have the newest Excel features.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(IF(J3="x",MOD(SEQUENCE(15,,18),24),SEQUENCE(15,,6)),RANDBETWEEN(1,15))`
This would work in Office365.

Where `MOD(SEQUENCE(15,,18),24)` is the range from 18 to 23 continuing into 0 to 8.
And `SEQUENCE(15,,6)` is the range from 6 to 20.

Example of sequences:
[image]

Wrapping them in INDEX and RANDBETWEEN returning the row number it returns a random selection from the 1st or 2nd sequence, depending on the value in `J3`. No helpers required.

[image]